# The argument type 'RequestOptions' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Options'. i am getting error after updating dio: 3.0.9 to dio: ^4.0.1

Tags: android, flutter, dio

i am getting this issue after updating libraries.Can anybody suggest me any solution.

```
final _result = await _dio.request<Map<String, dynamic>>('device',
    queryParameters: queryParameters,
    options: RequestOptions(
        method: 'POST',
        headers: <String, dynamic>{},
        extra: _extra,
        baseUrl: baseUrl, path: 'device'),
    data: _data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RequestOptions` has been renamed to `Options`.
You can check the entire example [here](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/options.dart).

Comment: I renamed RequestOptions to Options but still, it is not working.
there was a baseUrl parameter in RequestOptions but in Options it is removed.

Comment: Please check the example. If you want to use baseUrl, you can use BaseOptions when you create the object.
And then use Options in get method

Answer (score 0):

After renaming it's started working

```
final _result = await _dio.request<Map<String, dynamic>>('device',
    queryParameters: queryParameters,
    options: Options(
        method: 'POST',
        headers: <String, dynamic>{},
        extra: _extra,
        ),
    data: _data);
```